# Click events displaying in Firefox Console

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

On clicking every event in Firefox browser it has to display X path and click event message in Firefox console. please suggest me how can i achieve this....!!!!
It must be add-on for Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by *click event message*, but you can just inject a content script that logs the click event's path:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.path);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply final i achieved but now am facing a new problem for sending click events in HTML page to server(Java application Executable jar file).

Comment: You'll have to start a new question for that or see if it's already been answered on StackOverflow. Feel free to accept this solution if it helped you.